# Resuming screen with UTF8 enabled breaks character input

Tags: gnu-screen, xterm, readline, unicode

## Overview of UTF8 screen re-attachment issues.

### Problem:

Creating a screen that uses UTF8 works perfectly until re-attaching said screen session.

### Steps:

```
ssh remothost
screen -U -S ttytter
[detach screen]
[exit ssh]
xterm -class 'xterm-ttytter' -geometry 175x20 \
  -title 'ttytter' -e ssh -t remotehost "screen -dU -r ttytter"
```

### Details

I am a really big fan of [ttytter](http://www.floodgap.com/software/ttytter) and have been using it for some time now.  I have recently started using xterm vs xfce4-terminal/gnome-terminal as I find it is much cleaner.  I am trying to use UTF8 for personal and professional reasons and I am still trying to work out a few bugs.

The initial attachment (creation) gives me UTF8 input that works like it should.  $TERM is **xterm-256colors** while $LANG is **en_US.UTF-8**.  This is also true once I re-attach the screen, although I am unable to use certain characters, such as backspace, which shows up as **^H**.

It seems that the issue is specific to the command I am issuing to re-attach the screen.  I am trying to figure out what it is that could be causing such an issue when I re-attach my UTF8 screen.  I have tried *-dr* and *-dU -r*, both of which are failing to solve my problem.  I have tried giving xterm the -u8 flag, giving me no change in behavior.

```
xterm -class 'xterm-ttytter' -geometry 175x20 \
-title 'ttytter' -e ssh -t remotehost "screen -dU -r ttytter"
```

The above causes problems.

```
ssh remotehost
screen -dU -r ttytter
```

The above works just fine.

### Settings

#### .screenrc

```
defc1 off
defutf8 on
utf8 on
```

#### .Xdefaults

```
xterm*utf8: 1
```

#### .bashrc

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

I will really appreciate any guidance on solving this issue.

Comment: The problem lies within me setting xterm's -class.  $TERM is correct, but something about the class is breaking character input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Different 'classes' load different configuration files from **/etc/X11/app-default/**.  My problem was that my new xterm class did not have a matching configuration file.

```
# cd /etc/X11/app-default
# ln -s XTerm-color xterm-ttytter
```

The above will link XTerm-color's class settings for xterm-ttytter by creating a symbolic link.  This way, any changes that are made to XTerm-color will automatically be applied to xterm-ttytter as well.

Credit goes to @Nei on [Freenode/#xterm](http://irc.freenode.net) for explaining program classes for X11.

Comment: *ttytter -readline* is essential, as well.

Answer (score 1):

The applications defaults files for `xterm` are designed to include `XTerm-color` using a different route.  This resource

```
*customization: -color
```

would tell the X Toolkit library to load a resource file ending with "-color".

There are several app-defaults files installed for `xterm`.  Looking at my `/etc/X11/app-defaults`, these are the main ones:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root         2400 Nov 27 2012    KOI8RXTerm
-rw-r--r--   1 root         3609 Nov 27 2012    UXTerm
-rw-r--r--   1 root        10112 Nov 27 2012    XTerm
```

and these are the color-customized ones:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root         6217 Nov 27 2012    KOI8RXTerm-color
-rw-r--r--   1 root         6209 Nov 27 2012    UXTerm-color
-rw-r--r--   1 root         6207 Nov 27 2012    XTerm-color
```

The [`XTerm`](http://www.netbsd.org/~cegger/X11/app-defaults/XTerm) and [`XTerm-color`](http://www.netbsd.org/~cegger/X11/app-defaults/XTerm-color) ones should require little explanation: the default class is `XTerm`, and the customization resource adds "-color".  The others use different classes.  You should be interested in the `UXTerm` class, since it sets this

```
    *VT100.utf8:    1
```

as well as setting up fonts useful with UTF-8.  The `uxterm` script runs `xterm` using the `UXTerm` class, as well as ensuring that the locale environment variables are setup.

Further reading:

- [4. More X Configuration](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/XWindow-User-HOWTO/moreconfig.html) (The X Window User HOWTO)
- [Debian Bug #167495: xterm: /etc/X11/app-defaults/XTerm-color shouldn't define unnecessary resources](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=167495)
- [uxterm - X terminal emulator for Unicode (UTF-8) environments](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/uxterm.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're getting garbled output, and if that's the case, try running the `reset` command, or maybe `stty sane`. This will treat the symptom, at least.